# React-Native send PDF in JSON

Tags: react-native

In my React Native app I have to send a PDF file from local file system to a backend server with POST. It needs to be in Uint8Array format. As for now I can properly pick a file from local file system, which gives me its absolute path. How should I put it in a JSON body along with some other content?

**EDIT:** I managed to solve this problem by doing

```
RNFS.readFile(filePath, 'ascii')
    .then((res) => {
        const data = res.split("").map(x => x.charCodeAt(0));
        let uint8array = new TextEncoder("ascii").encode(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

`var string = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(uint8array);`

and set this string in your JSON before sending it?

Comment: But I only have a path to this file. I think I need to convert this path to a blob and then that blob to Uint8Array, though I'm not sure. I don't quite understand what you meant with your solution

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't get your question well, you want to send a POST request with a JSON body containing an encoded PDF right?

Comment: That's right. And alongside this encoded PDF there should be some other properties in the body of the JSON, too

Comment: can this help you ? https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/405/how-to-convert-pdf-to-text-extract-text-from-pdf-with-javascript